# Android getView() in BaseAdapter not called (but getCount() is called)

Tags: android

There no errors but the ListView is empty. I have implemented getCount() which returns right number of items in my ArrayList. And the ListView is visibility。
I had call setListAdapter on the ListView,and the xml is match_parent.

This is my Fragment.

```
 mNewsList = infoBean.getNews();
        if (mNewsList != null) {
            mNewsAdapter = new NewsAdapter();
            mListView.setAdapter(mNewsAdapter);
            mNewsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    } else {//load more
        List<HomeBean.NewsBean> news = infoBean.getNews();
        if (mNewsList != null) {
            mNewsList.addAll(news);
            mNewsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

This is my Adapter:

```
private class NewsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNewsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public HomeBean.NewsBean getItem(int position) {
        return mNewsList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = View.inflate(MyApplication.getmContext(), R.layout.item_list, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.ivIcon = convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_item);
            holder.tvTitle = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_list_title);
            holder.content = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_list_content);
            holder.tvTime = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
            holder.author = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_author);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.tvTitle.setText(getItem(position).getTitle());
        holder.content.setText(getItem(position).getContent());
        SimpleDateFormat dataFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String itemTime = dataFormat.format(getItem(position).getCreate_at() * 1000);
        holder.tvTime.setText(itemTime);
        holder.author.setText(getItem(position).getSection_name());
        if (getItem(position).getCover_pic().startsWith("http:")) {
            picUrl = getItem(position).getCover_pic();
        } else {
            picUrl = RBConstants.SERVER_PIC + getItem(position).getCover_pic();
        }
        HttpLoader.getInstance(MyApplication.getmContext()).display(holder.ivIcon, picUrl);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

This is my holder.

```
class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView ivIcon;
    public TextView tvTitle;
    public TextView tvTime;
    public TextView content;
    public TextView author;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `mNewsList` is not empty ? if the count is zero, the adapter won't call `getView` method. i think so.

Answer (score 0):

this is because   `mListView.setAdapter(mNewsAdapter);`  is never executed and of cource there is no need to call  `mNewsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` immediatelly after calling `mListView.setAdapter(mNewsAdapter);`

Answer (score -1):

`ListView` is old, please switch to [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html).